# Decompress / decompact JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq, pretty-print

I can compact JSON using `jq -c` like so:

```
cat file.json | jq -c
```

which will output all the json on a single line..is there a command that can decompact/decompress it so it's more human readable again? Basically adding newlines in the right places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is the [basic JQ filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) (jq by default pretty-prints all output)

`cat file.json | jq -c | jq .`

`jq .` will decompress it

Comment: you can do without the `.` but it's a good practice  ... in case some default behavior changes in the future